# PHP removing several things from a string at once

Tags: php, string, substr, strpos

I have a string like this being entered into my database that I can't format before it gets stored :

```
image/upload/v1440427262/hglz466d8mm1pazysaoh.jpg#32e2e9a111a4f9f4aa01dbad2ca2aa403c994d28
```

The only part of that string that I want to use is this :

```
hglz466d8mm1pazysaoh.jpg
```

I'm trying to use strpos to remove the excess data.

So far I've managed to remove everything after and including the hashtag

($data is the original string) :

```
$dataclean = substr($data, 0, strpos($data, "#"));
```

This works as expected with $dataclean returning :

```
image/upload/v1440427262/hglz466d8mm1pazysaoh.jpg
```

But I don't know how to remove the rest of the excess data :

```
image/upload/v1440427262/
```

Also, can this all be done in one hit or does it have to be split into several operations?

Comment: For the last part, you could use **$temp = explode("/",$dataclean);  $image = $temp[3];**

Comment: Or with regex: `$dataclean = preg_replace('~.*/|#.*~', "", $data);`

Comment: I've gone for the basename / strpos approach as I read that it is faster than regex and I'm using this function to update a newly created database entry. Not sure how true that statement is or if what I'm doing is a particularly safe thing to do but it seems to be working.

Comment: @Grant [did a little benchmark](https://eval.in/421770). With 10k loops slowest was the regex (with pcre_study flag bit faster as without) and fasted was pure explode: `$dataclean = explode("#", end(explode("/", $data)))[0];` Almost as fast: The selected answer :]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
$dataclean = basename(substr($data, 0, strpos($data, "#")));
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question, first remove values after `#` using

`$link = substr($data, 0, strpos($data, "#"));`

Then use `basename()` function to access filename from the URL.

For example,

```
    $link = "http://example.com/folderPath/filename.php";
    echo basename($link);  // It will return filename.php
```

Comment: This would also return data after the hash. You would need to include removing that in the `basename` function.

Comment: @ride_85027: I merely mentioned the concept with the example itself. The question already contains the solution for removing values after `#` using `substr`.

Answer (score 1):

If basename() doesn't work I would explode the string by the forward slash.

```
$data = 'image/upload/v1440427262/hglz466d8mm1pazysaoh.jpg#32e2e9a111a4f9f4aa01dbad2ca2aa403c994d28';
$pieces = explode("/", $data);

$dataclean = substr($pieces[3], 0, strpos($data, "#"));
```

Comment: Why `basename` shouldn't work? And that should be `substr($pieces[count($pieces)-1], 0, strpos($data, "#"));` otherwise you need to know every time the array index to get

Comment: Thanks for adding that tidbit of code. I believe basename is the best answer to this question. I don't know why it wouldn't work but if it doesn't this is another way to possibly do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with `substr + strpos`, but it looks like your string is a URL, so you could use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to isolate the path before using `basename`. Just another option FYI.

```
basename(parse_url($yourString, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex function:

```
preg_match("/[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{3}/i", $input_line, $output_array);
```

[Try the code](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/cog)